# Why there is not result for my pipeline GridSearchCV when I run my python code as following?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, grid-search

Recently I've faced issue on my python code as following:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
import datetime

time_stamp_start = datetime.datetime.now()
print('Starting time is: {}'.format(time_stamp_start.strftime('%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S')))

data = pd.read_csv('Train_movie.csv')
X_train = data.Message
y_train = data.label

Count = CountVectorizer(stop_words = 'english')
# stop_words, ngram_range=(1, 1), max_df=1.0,  max_features=None
lda = LatentDirichletAllocation()
#n_components=10, learning_method='batch', learning_decay=.7, learning_offset=10.
mbb = MultinomialNB()
#Before Process
print('Processing Before...')
#Processing
ppl_bayes = Pipeline([('count',Count),('lda',lda),('mbb',mbb)])
param_grid = [{'count__ngram_range':[(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)],
        'count__max_df':[0.1,0.5,0.9],
        'lda__n_components':[7,10,12],
        'lda__learning_method':['online'],
        'lda__learning__decay':[.7,.9],
        'mbb__alpha':[1.0]},
        {'count__ngram_range':[(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)],
        'count__max_df':[0.1,0.5,0.9],
        'lda__n_components':[7,10,12],
        'lda__learning_method':['batch'],
        'mbb__alpha':[1.0]}]
print('Processing now...')
gs_ppl_bayes = GridSearchCV(estimator = ppl_bayes, param_grid = param_grid, scoring = 'accuracy',
    cv = 5, n_jobs = -1)

print('Processing done!!')
gs_ppl_bayes.fit(X_train, y_train)

print('Mission processing...')
print(gs_ppl_bayes.best_params_)
time_stamp_end = datetime.datetime.now()
print('Ending time is: {}'.format(time_stamp_end.strftime('%Y.%m.%d-%H:%M:%S')))
```

I wanna use GridSearchCV to tune my best hyperparameters. It is good to show these results:

```
Starting time is: 2020.08.31-15:15:06
Processing Before...
Processing now...
Processing done!!
```

However, there is no other following results after I've waited for approximately 4 hours!!! What is the issues? I gonna insane for it.

Thanks in advance!! Guys!!

Comment: Try fitting the pipeline without the grid search, and multiply the time taken by 81 (the size of your grid) to get an estimate for how long it should take, ignoring parallelism.  Also try setting the verbose parameter so you can see progress (Though that might require setting `n_jobs=1`.)

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal, reproducible example of your code? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Your current code can not run without the missing 'Train_movie.csv' dataset.